# Why can't PGP/GPG Web-of-Trust be automated?

Tags: email, pgp, web-of-trust

We heard lots of complaints about hard to use crypto tools, and recent ideas of [Google](https://code.google.com/p/end-to-end/wiki/KeyDistribution) how to fix this. I had another idea about this which seems quite obvious, but couldn't find anything about it on the web.

The idea would be to automate the PGP Web-of-Trust by loosening crypto requirements, following the [Opportunistic Security](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-dukhovni-opportunistic-security-00) idea.

The email client would automatically look up the PGP key of all receivers in key stores (first local, then public keyservers, ideally provided by the receiving email provider) and encrypt the mail with these keys. Ideally, we would use trusted keys by regular PGP standards. However, we would fall back to any suitable key with less trust, down to a complete unknown key if required.

On the sending side, any email client would automatically create a PGP key locally and publish the public key part on the email provider's keyserver. The client obviously needs to provide a way to define/import our own key for advanced users.

By these defaults, we would have more/most emails encrypted, by itself an arguable advantage (to increase surveillance costs).

The only "new" idea here would be to automatically manage trust by exploiting social assumptions. The main assumption would be that two parties continuously exchanging emails somehow know each other and can identify each other by the contents of the mails exchanged. With each email exchange, the email clients of both parties would increase their internal trust score for the other party's key. This internal trust score would be applied like traditional Web-of-Trust confidence levels to build up an automated Web-of-Trust.

We would keep the internal trust score separate from traditional confidence level for two reasons:

1. The internal trust score needs to be very fine-grained in order to allow automated increments and calculation (e. g. 0..1 range with IEEE-754 double precision).
2. Automatically crated trust scores are better than none, but will never reach the explicit confidence levels of the traditional Web-of-Trust.

For me, this seems like a suitable approach for the public part of the key management issue. It does not solve the private part (e. g. getting the private key to all mobile devices). We also inherit all known issues of PGP.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing some major issue here. Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 7):

### Certificate Authorities

> The email client would automatically look up the PGP key of all receivers in key stores (first local, then public keyservers, ideally provided by the receiving email provider) and encrypt the mail with these keys. Ideally, we would use trusted keys by regular PGP standards. However, we would fall back to any suitable key with less trust, down to a complete unknown key if required.

This is a horribly bad idea. Everyone can generate keys for every mail address. Without any trust path, you have no chance to decide which one is the right key. Instead of further argumentation, have a look at the [key server results for `president@whitehouse.gov`](http://pool.sks-keyservers.net:11371/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=president%40whitehouse.gov). Don't expect *any* of them to belong to who they claim to be.

> On the sending side, any email client would automatically create a PGP key locally and publish the public key part on the email provider's keyserver.

Now we're getting on a more reasonable path. But: This somewhat counterfeits the idea behind OpenPGP. Trust is not defined by on which key server is stored, but what keys are trusted. You're looking for a certification authority (yes, in the end pretty much the same thing like X.509 uses). There are already some in the OpenPGP world, have a look at [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org).

Your provider could also be a certificate authority (to some degree, you're already trusting him anyway). To do so, you would both sign and (fully) trust his certificate authority key, in return he's signing all keys generated for his own users. OpenPGP can do all this out of the box; no need to change it. *You just need to make people understand and implement it.*

### An Automated Web of Trust

> The only "new" idea here would be to automatically manage trust by exploiting social assumptions. The main assumption would be that two parties continuously exchanging emails somehow know each other and can identify each other by the contents of the mails exchanged. With each email exchange, the email clients of both parties would increase their internal trust score for the other party's key. This internal trust score would be applied like traditional Web-of-Trust confidence levels to build up an automated Web-of-Trust.

Now we're getting to a completely different concept, which is already known as *certificate pinning* (but I haven't heard of it being implemented for OpenPGP).

Yes, this might be reasonable for people you already had contact with. But it makes things much more complicated, especially regarding computation of trust. This would require a *probabilistic* computation of trust to be able to deal with the large number of rather low trust issued by such a system, like proposed by Maurer et al. in 1996: [Modeling a public-key infrastructure](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=11935395757986484784&hl=de&as_sdt=0,5&as_vis=1); maybe together with automated issuance of trust.

### Conclusion

Your first proposal, providers acting as certificate authorities has indeed some charm, is compatible with OpenPGP and rather easy to implement. I'm not sure if Google even has similar plans for its [End to End project](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.de/2014/06/making-end-to-end-encryption-easier-to.html).

> For me, this seems like a suitable approach for the public part of the key management issue. It does not solve the private part (e. g. getting the private key to all mobile devices). We also inherit all known issues of PGP.

Probabilistic models have already been proposed nearly twenty years ago, there just was nobody to pick them up. If you [scroll through the citations for the paper linked above](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?cites=11935395757986484784&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=de), it even seems quite a bunch of publications claim to have solutions for your proposal. One large problem is, this wouldn't be compatible with OpenPGP (as defined by RFC 4880) any more, and introducing new systems in a way they get acceptance isn't very easy. Furthermore, it's even harder to understand what's going on in probabilistic models.

Another thing is you'd still have to teach people on how to use OpenPGP and understand the Web of Trust concept. This is no technical problem (although it might be more complicated than necessary); there is no plain technical solution for security. Don't just make people assume their communication is secure when they're not able to understand what's going on, [bad things happen if people do so](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/09/what-jennifer-lawrence-can-teach-you-about-cloud-security/), or a horrible bunch of dismissed, non-revoked keys on the key servers.

---

### Further Notes

> 1. The internal trust score needs to be very fine-grained in order to allow automated increments and calculation (e. g. 0..1 range with IEEE-754 double precision).

Off topic regarding what's really discussed in this Q&A, but anyway: this is no reasonable use case for floating-point values. Floating point numbers have high resolution around 0, but this degrades quickly when going towards larger values (I was told you can observe this in Minecraft, where some funny jumps occur when you get near the borders of the world). Why not just map it to the whole 64 bit integer (32 bit probably would be more than fine, too) which occupies the same space, but with a constant resolution of all values. Using floating-point variables you'd have to limit yourself to a very small value range (0..1 would probably be fine, but still then you have to [deal with funny effects not too important for probabilistic calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14741188/695343) and waste some memory and computational power.

Answer (score 1):

There is possible for one type of "automated web of trust", and that is DKIM.

DKIM works by the signer (domain owner) publishes the key in DNS. Since only the owner of the domain can publish things in DNS, security is gained this way.
Combining this with DNSSEC, you have a completely automated web of trust for SIGNING.

However, this is not E2E. Instead, this works like standard ID cards.

---

Here im going to make a IRL example:

A government or bank assert your identity, and issues a ID card. The verifier of a ID card TRUST that the government or bank does not issue ID cards bearing the wrong identity, thus are trusted.
I can issue ID cards if I want too. With my logo and my design. Then its up to people if they trust my issuance.
Issuing "internal" ID cards are pretty common in some high security Corporations, where the ID card must be visible at all times inside high security areas.
Thus, if the clerk in the shop, when you are going to buy alcohol, trust the Company that issue the internal ID card, then the clerk can trust the ID card like a government issued one. (but the clerk will be blamed if its found out that the ID card was falsely issued and he sell alcohol to a minor)

---

Same here with DKIM.
When you verify the identitiy using DKIM, you trust the email server to not sign emails that are not authenticated (either via IP or password, its up to the mail server to authenticate its end users). So if we have a example email adress "sebastian.nielsen@sebbe.eu". When I send a email through my mail server, my mailserver signs this mail using the DKIM key for "sebbe.eu".
You as a receiver, either your mail server or the mail client, can use the DKIM signature header, to look up the public key for "sebbe.eu" and do verification.
Now you know for real that its the server at "sebbe.eu" that signed the mail.
Now its up to you, if you trust my server to actually assert that "sebastian.nielsen" actually is a member of "sebbe.eu". It depends of if you trust "sebbe.eu". This provided that the identity alignment is strict (eg the signer domain matches the "From:" and MAIL FROM domain)
This means, that if you know that Im not going to issue email adresses in the form "firstname.lastname@sebbe.eu" for users that are not named firstname.lastname, then you can trust that a DKIM signed mail from firstname.lastname@sebbe.eu is really from a person named "firstname lastname". The trust circle is complete!

Since mail content is also signed with DKIM, you can be assured that the mail was not modified in transit after have been signed.

---

A good idea is to exchange PGP public keys using DKIM signed mail. Then you know for real that its completely safe.
You dont need to enter any web of trust to use DKIM trust structure to Exchange public keys.

---

Thus DKIM with DNSSEC-signed keys, are one form of a completely safe automated web of trust, provided that you trust the signing mail server.

Answer (score 0):

If an Email client automatically publishes information about the amount of emails that I exchange with every one, it can keep the content of those emails private but it's still a problem.

The client shouldn't tell everyone who asks how much emails I exchanged with which lawyer.

Just remember the [Google Buzz privacy fiasco](http://www.cnet.com/news/google-buzz-privacy-nightmare/) when Google automatically used data about exchanged emails to set public followership of Buzz accounts.